# How to create our own function and how to call in the Ajax in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to create my own function using jquery.And I want to call that function in the Ajax.and the calling function should not be like $('div').myfunctionname();

Comment: ok first can you tell me how to create our function in the jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so complicated here is the tutorial from [Jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

The format to create a plugin/function is this

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>User Function Ajax with Jquery </TITLE>
<SCRIPT src='jquery-1.4.js' LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$.fn.changecontent = function(result) {

alert(result);
    $(result).find('record').each(function(){
        var from=$(this).find('from').text();
        var to=$(this).find('to').text();
        var sub=$(this).find('sub').text();
        $('div#loading').append('<table border="2"><tr><td>'+from+'</td></tr><tr><td>'+to+'</td></tr><tr><td>'+sub+'</td></tr></table>');
    });
};
$.ajax({url:"Ajax.xml", success:function(result){
     $().changecontent(result);
}});
});
 </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <div id='loading'/>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```